# How do I add or remove rows from UITableView at runtime?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm sure this a very nooby question, but I can't figure it out.  I have a UITextField *numberOfPointsTextBox which allows my users to input an integer.  I want this value to be the number of rows in the UITableView *myTableView which is in the same view as the numberOfPointsTextBox.  I also want the user to be able to change this value and have the number of cells update accordingly.  The only solution that I have been able to find is to create a "for" loop which would create an NSIndexPath for each, but there must be a better solution out there.  Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of rows the `UITableView` displays is controlled through `UITableViewDataSource`'s `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method. Your code should listen to changes of `UITextField *numberOfPointsTextBox`, update the number of points in your custom instance of the `UITableViewDataSource` with which you have configured your `UITableView`, and finally call `reloadData` on the `UITableView` to complete the update.

Comment: Wow, I feel very stupid now. lol I set the tableView's delegate but forgot the dataSource.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the value returned in your `numberOfRowsInSection` which will then cause the table to only render that many rows.

So, when your `numberOfPoints` text box has a change in value, call a `reloadData` on your tableView and then use the value from your text box in `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Answer (score 0):

Your tableview datasource must be configurable, so you can set up number of items after user has entered some value in text field. After that you can just call -reloadData method of your UITableView instance, that will force table view to re-query all items from datasource